# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la información de todos los marcadores dentro de un polígono dibujado?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Tengo marcadores pintados en un mapa con la librería de google-map-react, también puedo dibujar un polígono o alguna figura geométrica utilizando google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager, lo que quiero hacer ahora es obtener los datos de todos los marcadores que estén dentro del polígono para poder por ejemplo mandar una notificación o cosas así, pero no tengo idea de como obtener los datos de los marcadores dentro del polígono dibujado.
[image: Necesito obtener la información de los marcadores dentro del polígono dibujado]

Answer (score -1):

Suponiendo que sabes las coordenadas `x,y` de cada pin, las `vertices` del polígono y el polígono es **convexo**, solo tienes que verificar si el punto esta dentro del polígono...

```
function isInsidePolygon(point,polygonVertices){

    let numFloats = polygonVertices.length;
    let intersects = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numFloats; i += 2) {
        let x1 = polygonVertices[i];
        let y1 = polygonVertices[i + 1];
        let x2 = polygonVertices[(i + 2) % numFloats];
        let y2 = polygonVertices[(i + 3) % numFloats];
        if (((y1 <= point.y && point.y < y2) || (y2 <= point.y && point.y < y1)) && point.x < ((x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1) * (point.y - y1) + x1)) 
            intersects++;
    }
    return (intersects & 1) == 1;
}
```

Si el polígono es **cóncavo** tendrás que triangular el polígono, es decir convertirlo en varios triángulos, pues todos los triángulos son polígonos **convexos**.

Puedes usar una librería para triangular polígonos... el código se vera algo asi...

```
let pinsDentroDelPolygono = [];

for(let i = 0; i < pins.length; i++){
   let pin = pins[i];
   if(isPinInsidePolygon(pin,polygon))
      pinsDentroDelPolygono.push(pin);
}


function isPinInsidePolygon(pin,polygon){
    for(let i = 0; i < polygon.triangles.length; i++){
          let triangle = polygon.triangles[i];
          if(isInsidePolygon({x:pin.x,y:pin.y},triangle.vertices))
              return true;

    }
    return false;

}
```